# How are hybrid keyframes created in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, keyframes, frame-interpolation

As I understand, there are 2 types of keyframes in AE: basic (Linear, Bezier, Continuous Bezier, Auto Bezier, Hold) and hybrid ones. Here is a picture from the [site](https://thesbit.com/types-of-keyframes-in-after-effects/) I read:
[image]

It’s clear for me about the basic ones, but I’m totally confused with the hybrid keyframes. There's a quote from the same [site](https://thesbit.com/types-of-keyframes-in-after-effects/):

> By default, a keyframe would use only one type of Temporal
> Interpolation (linear for example). But in some cases, a keyframe
> might show dual nature as well. Which means one half of the keyframe
> is Linear (incoming/outgoing) while the other half could be Hold or
> Bezier (e.g. Toggle Hold or Ease In/Out settings). This is something
> that I call hybrid keyframes.

As I understand it, the right part of the key should show the previous key, and the second part should show the subsequent key. But this doesn't happen:
[image]

Apparently I misunderstand it. So, how does this actually work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think only the symbols shown in your diagram are the available ones in after effects. If you make three temporal keyframes:

1. linear
2. easy ease
3. auto bezier

Then change the middle one (2) to be a hold keyframe, you'll see one of the hybrid examples shown (hold ease in).

[image: grab]

In general, the keyframe symbols are a great useful way to get certain kinds of motion working quickly, but it's often clearer to understand what's going on by separating dimensions and looking at the graph mode.